# tailwindcss, transform doesn't work but it does when added in css

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css

I started using tailwindcss recently and I noticed that some properties don't work at all but when I put them in css they do work as expected. Here is an example.

```js
const Step = styled.div`
  box-shadow: 0 1.3px 12px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  :hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); 
  }
  ${tw`
    flex
    rounded-lg
    items-center
    justify-center
    pl-10
    pr-10
    pt-6
    pb-6
  `}
`;
```

The above works because I added the hover effect inside my styled component with css.
But this:

```js
const Step = styled.div`
  box-shadow: 0 1.3px 12px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  ${tw`
    flex
    rounded-lg
    items-center
    justify-center
    pl-10
    pr-10
    pt-6
    pb-6
    hover:scale-110
  `}
`;
```

Doesn't apply the hover effect.
Why does that happen?

Edit (code-sanbox):
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-starter-forked-wwvw2?file=/src/App.js

Try to replace the hover effect on top with `hover:scale-110` inside twin-macro

Comment: typo `hover: scale-110` -> `hover:scale-110`

Comment: @doğukan changed it but still didnt fix the issue.

Comment: you are using tailwindcss >3.x.x ?

Comment: @doğukan 3.0.5, I have used hover effect in the same project but for example this specific one doesn't work

Comment: How did you install tailwind? Is the class showing up in the browser on the component if you set the hover state?

Comment: Are you using `twin.macro`, `tailwind-styled-components`, or `tailwind.macro`? A minimal reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6k54y) would be very helpful to understand your setup.

Comment: @onkar ruikar added a sandbox for you to check it out, check the edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `GlobalStyles` from twin.macro resolved the issue on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-starter-forked-jnzrk?file=/src/App.js). For more info refer [this issue](https://gitmemory.cn/repo/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/issues/542).

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import React from "react";

import tw from "twin.macro";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { GlobalStyles } from "twin.macro";

const Step = styled.div`
  box-shadow: 0 1.3px 12px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  ${tw`
    flex
    rounded-lg
    items-center
    justify-center
    pl-10
    pr-10
    pt-6
    pb-6
    hover:scale-150
  `}
`;
const Title = styled.h1`
  ${tw`
    pl-10
    pr-10
    pt-6
    pb-6
    hover:rotate-90 
    hover:bg-green-500
  `}
`;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello world");
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Title>Title</Title>
      <Step>Test</Step>
      <GlobalStyles />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That indeed solved my issue too! Thank you so much and sorry for rushing with the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

From the Tailwind side, the issue is that the variable definition for `--tw-transform` gets left out of the final CSS.

When setting `` tw`hover:scale-110` `` in the code sandbox, I get the following CSS:

```css
.iKmGvP:hover {
    --tw-scale-x: 1.1;
    --tw-scale-y: 1.1;
    -webkit-transform: var(--tw-transform);
    -ms-transform: var(--tw-transform);
    transform: var(--tw-transform);
}
```

The `--tw-transform` variable is defined [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/v3.0.8/src/corePlugins.js#L541-L549), and just concatenates the variables defined by the different transform classes.

It's probably a configuration issue with `twin.macro`, Tailwind, or both, which leads to that definition not being picked up. I'm not experienced enough with `twin.macro` to see whether the setup in the code sandbox looks sane.

I do see however that you have the typical `tailwind.css` file with calls to `@tailwind base;` etc. As far as I can see, that file isn't referenced anywhere. In a vanilla Tailwind project, that would be a likely culprit. Not sure if it's needed at all when using `twin.macro`.

Comment: Not sure but as far as I know it isn't needed to reference that in twin.macro but I may be wrong. I assume that by the fact that hover effects and scale does work in other elements and I only faced the issue with <div>. Sounds weird.